# unable to get the desired output while date formatting

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

While running the below java code

```
String v_date_str = "03/04/2015";
Date v_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY").parse(v_date_str);
DateFormat formatter = null;

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date date_temp = null;
date_temp = (Date) formatter.parse("31-Dec-2012"); // String of same format a formatter
out.println("output: " + formatter.format(v_date));
```

i was expecting output as below.

```
output: 03-MAR-2015
```

but i am getting output as

```
output: 28-Dec-2014
```

please let me know where am i going wrong and how can i fix this.

Thanks

Comment: DD is day in year, while dd is day in month. could that be causing a problem?

Comment: `D` and `Y` are misused

Comment: Try `MM/dd/yyyy` for your first format string.

Comment: Hi @GriffeyDog, this is working awesome, but a small question, i want to insert this output into my database table using ps.setDate(), can you please help me on how can i do this. Thanks

Comment: @Rakesh That is subject for entirely new question. Try to do it yourself and if you will have problems which are not explained in tutorial and already asked questions feel free to post another question in which you will explain your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are parsing the date with the wrong format. `D` is the day in the year, not the day in the month, which is `d`. `Y` is the week year, not the year, which is `y`. Once you fix the format, the code executes just as you expect:

```
Date v_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(v_date_str);
```

Comment: this is working awesome, but a small question, i want to insert this output into my database table using ps.setDate(), can you please help me on how can i do this. Thanks

Comment: @Rakesh if you have a different question, please post another question, with all the relevant details - it's pretty hard to answer like this.